# UICollectionView cell draws top left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

This is my first time working with UICollectionView.

I've got everything set up and laid out as it should be (as far as I know).  I've had a little bit of difficulty with the way the dequeue function works for the UICollectionView, but I think I've gotten past that.  It was tricky setting up my custom cell classes when I didn't know if initWithFrame would be called or prepareForReuse.

I'm pretty sure the problem lies within the prepareForReuse function, but *where* is the question.

**What happens is, the cells will apparently randomly draw at the top-left of the collection view and some cells will not be where they belong in the grid.  (see image attached)**

When bouncing, scrolling, and zooming (so as to cause reuse to occur), the problem happens.  Randomly a slide will appear in the top left, and other slides will randomly disappear from the grid.

( I need more rep to post an image.  Ugh.  :| If you can help me, I'll email you the image.  bmantzey@mac.com )

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

Slide* thisSlide = [_presentation.slidesInEffect objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[BuilderSlide prepareWithSlide:thisSlide];

BuilderSlide* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlainSlide" forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;}
```

I'm using a static method to set the Slide object, which contains the data necessary to either prepare the asynchronous download or retrieve the image from disk cache.

It's simply:

```
+(void)prepareWithSlide:(Slide*)slide{
if(s_slide)
    [s_slide release];

s_slide = [slide retain];}
```

I'm not sure if it's a big no-no to do this but in my custom Cell class, I'm calling prepareForReuse in the initWithFrame block because I need that setup code to be the same:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if(self)
{
    [self prepareForReuse];
}
return self;}
```

Here's the prepareForReuse function:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
CGSize size = [SpringboardLayout currentSlideSize];
[self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
self.size = size;

// First remove any previous view, so as not to stack them.
if(_builderSlideView)
{
    if(_builderSlideView.slide.slideID == s_slide.slideID)
        return;

    [_builderSlideView release];
}

for(UIView* aView in self.contentView.subviews)
{
    if([aView isKindOfClass:[BuilderSlideView class]])
    {
        [aView removeFromSuperview];
        break;
    }
}

// Then setup the new view.
_builderSlideView = [[BuilderSlideView alloc] initWithSlide:s_slide];
self.builderCellView = _builderSlideView;
[s_slide release];
s_slide = nil;

[self.contentView addSubview:_builderSlideView];

if([SlideCache isImageCached:_builderSlideView.slide.slideID forPresentation:_builderSlideView.slide.presentationID asThumbnail:YES])
{
    [_builderSlideView loadImageFromCache];
}
else
{
    [_builderSlideView loadView];
}}
```

Finally, when the slide image has been downloaded, a Notification is posted (I plan on changing this to a delegate call).  The notification simply reloads the cell that has received an update.  Here's the notification code:

```
-(void)didLoadBuilderCellView:(NSNotification*)note{
BuilderCellView* cellView = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:@"cell"];
BuilderSlideView* slideView = (BuilderSlideView*)cellView;
NSIndexPath* indexPath = [self indexPathForSlide:slideView.slide];
if(indexPath)
    [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];}
```

Note that the slide objects exist in the model.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this problem?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention loadView will queue the slide for download.  The receipt of the image caches the image and posts a notification.  Thanks again.

Comment: Is initWithFrame being called? It's not clear to me why you're removing and adding subviews. Why not add the subviews in the custom cell's init method (probably initWithCoder:) an be done with it? It also doesn't makes sense to call prepareForReuse in an init method, since the cell is brand new at that point.

Comment: Are you using a custom layout or `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?

Comment: Both.  It's a subclass of UiCollectionViewFlowLayout.

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the purpose of the dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier method.  It either calls initWithFrame or prepareForReuse, right?  It finds a UICollectionViewCell object and returns it.  The state of that cell could have pointers pointing at whatever subviews were set up before the cell scrolled out of view, therefore requiring it to be reset to images that match the model at the cell that will now be used.  I want the init and the prepForReuse to do the same thing.  Yes, initWithFrame is being called.

Comment: So, I tried removing the code in prepareForReuse and putting that in init only.  As I expected, reused cells would have apparently random images in them.  It's showing the view that was present in the cell that matched the model at the time it was initialized.  Reusing that cell, the image must be updated to match the model.

Comment: It looks like what's happening is I have some recursion going on.  The dequeue causes a reload on the cell that acquires its image.  That reload causes a dequeue, etc.  What I'll need to do is follow this lazy loading technique used in loading the UITableView in the following example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html . Since UITableView and UICollectionView data source protocols are almost the same, I can follow the pattern in the example code.  Hopefully that will solve my woes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that was causing the cells to draw top left and/or disappear was caused by infinite recursion on a background thread.  Plain and simply, I wasn't implementing the lazy loading correctly and safely.  To solve this problem, I went back to the drawing board and tried again.  Proper implementation of a lazy loading algorithm did the trick.